# Probability of having two pairs of earrings when choosing six earrings from 10 pairs

Tags: probability

> Ten distinct pairs of earrings are in a box and six earrings are randomly
>   selected  without  replacement. Find the probability that exactly two
>   pairs are selected.

Can anyone help me with this, and possibly explain the solution? Right now, I have $\binom{10}2/\binom{20}6$.

Comment: The code `\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{20}{6}}` yields the fraction $$\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{20}{6}}\;.$$ There’s a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $$ \frac{\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}4}{\binom{20}{6}}\approx 13\%. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the fact that there are $\binom{20}{6}$ possible selections of the six earrings; I see you already know that.  Now count the number of ways you can select precisely two pairs and two oddballs among the six:

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to select which of the ten pairs you have picked.

Then there are $\binom{8}{2}$ ways to select which two of the eight remaining pairs you have picked one earring out of.

Then there are $2\times 2 = 4$ ways to select the particular two oddballs out of their pairs.

The answer is 
$$
\frac{ 4 \times \binom{10}{2} \times \binom{8}{2} } {\binom{20}{6}} = \frac{42}{323}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The concept of choosing from the entire set in the denominator and from pairs in the numerator isn't intuitive at all to me. But the answer makes sense.